Blender, inside of Ubuntu, inside of Termux, inside of Android, in my phone - Won't work with hardware acceleration
I'm running Blender in a Linux (Ubuntu Noble) Virtual Machine on an Android Phone, using a ported tutorial, which enables me to have Hardware Acceleration for GPU.
All the tutorials I used to set up my Virtual Machine follows, sorted in order I used them:
https://ivonblog.com/en-us/posts/how-to-use-termux/ 
https://ivonblog.com/en-us/posts/termux-x11/ 
https://ivonblog.com/en-us/posts/termux-proot-distro-debian/ 
https://ivonblog.com/en-us/posts/termux-virglrenderer/
In the Debian tutorial I used "ubuntu" instead of "debian" as the Distribution name.
I have a Samsung Galaxy S20 5G (SM-G981B/DS) device, with Android 13, Termux from F-Droid and proot-distro latest versions both, Ubuntu Noble VM, Blender 4.0.2 with Ubuntu.
When trying to run Blender using hardware acceleration, I get this output:
Read prefs: "/home/myUserName/.config/blender/4.0/config/userpref.blend"
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Segmentation fault

And the blender.crash.txt have this contents:
# Blender 4.0.2, Unknown revision

# backtrace
blender(+0xa21c20) [0x3000a21c20]
blender(+0x7084f4) [0x30007084f4]
[0x707f305678]
blender(+0xaa5634) [0x3000aa5634]
blender(+0xa76760) [0x3000a76760]
blender(+0xa783dc) [0x3000a783dc]
blender(+0xa8dd28) [0x3000a8dd28]
blender(+0x6ad998) [0x30006ad998]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x284c4) [0x70797184c4]
/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0x98) [0x7079718598]
blender(+0x6f86b0) [0x30006f86b0]

# Python backtrace

I tried various acceleration methods, LLVM, VirGL and Zink, but no luck either.
And if I try without acceleration it works, but it's very slow.
I also tried with Debian by the way, and the results are different, in fact, I just can use Blender (3.4.1) with hardware acceleration and I can notice it because the interface is more reactive.
I tried to compile Blender 3.4.1 in Ubuntu and to run it with hardware acceleration, and it just works as it does on Debian.
So, I guess it's a problem with the new Blender version, and it's a problem with Blender itself.
Thanks in advance for any help, regards, have a nice day.

Here is the problem: I don't have OpenGL 4.3!!! If only I could set up my VirGL to emulate it, I could also run Blender.
